# How to use the "Resource Files" logical folder in Netbeans IDe for C/C++?

Tags: netbeans, resources

As can be seen in the below screenshot, a Netbeans C/C++ project allows the addition of resource files. When I Google things along the lines of "Netbeans C/C++ 'Resource Files," nothing useful comes up. As such, I ask here: what are they and how can I use them? Is it just a logical folder that the application can use at runtime with regular `fstream`s, or does it allow the embedding of files in the final executable similar to Java's `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` mechanism?

[image: Resouce Files logical folder under project]

NOTE: I am using g++ 5.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64 if these are platform independent in any way (in which case I would like to know how to use them on Windows and other versions of Linux as well).